# Is it always safe to remove a published empty section?

Tags: delphi, access-modifiers

I'm working on an old legacy project which have several classes in which the `published` section is always declared without anything inside of it, i.e:

```
TMyClass = class
public
   procedure DoSomething();
published
end;
```

On compiling, I get the following warning message:

> [DCC Warning] uMyUnit.pas(141): W1055 PUBLISHED caused RTTI ($M+) to
>   be added to type 'TMyClass'

I don't know if the predecessor developer has declared these `published` sections for some valid reason. 
Is it always safe to remove an empty `published` section or could it cause some changes in the application's behavior?

Comment: Code completion (CTRL+C) will often add these unused clauses if it has to create a public clause. It is safe to remove them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference for the class itself is none - however the important thing is that the default visibility of any class that inherits from a class with `{$M+}` then changes from public to published!

See this example code:

```
uses
  TypInfo;

type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    fName: string;
    property Name: string read fName;
  published
  end;

  TMyOtherClass = class(TMyClass)
    property Name;
  end;

var
  propCount, i: Integer;
  props: PPropList;
begin
  propCount := GetPropList(TypeInfo(TMyOtherClass), props);
  for i := 0 to propcount - 1 do
    Writeln(props^[i].Name);
  Readln;
end.
```

You can see that it lists the `Name` property but when you remove the published from `TMyClass` it will not - that is because once `TMyClass` got `{$M+}` added any member declared without explicitly stating the visibility it will be published opposed to public.

Also other members declared without visibility like fields will be published. This is being used in the streaming system Delphi uses for forms and such.
You can for example then call `TObject.FieldAddress` or `TObject.MethodAddress` passing in the name of a field or method and get back pointers to the field or method. It only works with published fields and methods.

This is how loading from a dfm sets up all those IDE generated fields like `Button1` or connects the `Button1Click` method to the `Button1.OnClick` - they are without explicit visibility at the top of your form which inherits from `TComponent` that has `{$M+}` declared.

Answer (score 3):

### It depends

Does the rest of the code actually require access to RTTI for the class?

Only `TPersistent`-derived classes have the `{$M+}` directlive applied to them by default without needing a `published` section.

A `published` section is used for DFM streaming, which requires RTTI. Non-persistent classes are not steamed in DFMs, but there are other uses for RTTI.

So, without knowing what the rest of the code does, it is not really known whether removing empty `published` sections is safe or not.

Comment: What exactly would differ for the "rest of the code" if the published section is empty anyway? What actually differ between a class with $M+ or without that does not have any published members?

Comment: I've searched for "rtti" in the projects and I didn't find anything. Which kind of instructions should I look for in order to be sure RTTI is not used?

Comment: Any uses on unit `TypInfo` would definitely be worth investigating.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well, I left that one out because he already said he didn't get a hit on "rtti", but yeah,  System.Rtti would also be on the red flag list.